# What does "waive off" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I understand that when you *waive* something you forego it or give it up. e.g.

> I waive my [right to] free coffee.

I also understand that a *waiver* is a document stating that you waive your rights to something, but I read the phase *waive off* and I don't quite understand it.

The context was

> personA: Live slugs!
>
> personB: Waive off! Waive off! This is just a practice run!

I see that *waive off* means *stop*, or *go away* or something like that but I can't exactly put a specific meaning to it.

What does *waive off* mean?

Comment: I think we need more context - *live slugs*? Was this a Monty Python skit? :)

Comment: @John C - Sadly this is all the context I have.

Comment: Sorry to come so late and still, if there's no more context, where did the text come from?

Whether or not Monty Python entered any race, it strikes me *live slugs* particularly in *a practice run* prolly is a military term, here meaning live *ammunition*.

Either way, even those who started seemed to stumble over why to *waive* isn't to *wave*.

I suspect Peter’s drivers only *waive* - never *waive off* qualification attempts. It would take a judge or marshal to *wave them off*. Presumably Tim’s sailors followed suit decades later…

To *waive* is to give up; to *wave off* is to abort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expression being used is *wave off,* not *waive off*.

[This website](http://www.getracinginfo.com/IndyCar/Tracks/Indianapolis-Motor-Speedway/facts.html) from the Indianapolis Speedway explains it quite well:

> Wave off – The process by which a team forfeits a qualification attempt. A driver or team
>   can “wave off” an attempt any time before the start of the fourth and final lap in the attempt.
>   If the run is waved off before the car takes the green flag, it does not count as one of the three
>   allowed attempts for that car. Once the green flag is waved to start the attempt, the run counts
>   as one attempt, even if it’s waved off.

If the context isn't auto racing (I assume it's not—what are live slugs doing in an auto race?), it's borrowed from auto racing, and has the same meaning.

Comment: this has credence

Comment: I think this makes most sense.

Comment: This is also the phrase used by the military when instructing a fighter pilot to abort a landing attempt, according to the definitive source of all Navy slang (*Top Gun*).

Comment: @Peter Shor: "what are live slugs doing in an auto race?" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snail_racing

Answer (score 9):

I believe the origin of the phrase was in aircraft carriers, which have (or at least had) a crewman standing by when a plane came in to land, with a pair of signalling bats.   One signal meant "lose height", another "cut power", and so on.  If, however, the pilot was coming in far too fast (or the wheels had not extended properly), the  batsman literally "waved the pilot off" the deck, and he went round again.

Comment: @Peter: I've seen nothing in anything that's been posted here that gives credence to the assertion that the racing usage of the term pre-dates the military usage of the term.  Ultimately, both answers are correct, and both answer the original question adequately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is slang, and Urban Dictionary does give a definition, although I don't know how much weight can be placed on this, but anyway, *waive off* means:

> When someone or something gets ignored or disregarded.

This seems to make sense when applied in the context given, where Person A gives some disheartening information, but Person b is shouting for the others to ignore what Person A is saying, as it is "just a practice run", and therefore, nothing to panic about.

Comment: The user-contributed definitions at the Urban Dictionary often mix up homonyms and should not be relied upon exclusively for anything but the newest slang terms.

Answer (score 0):

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=waive%20off):

> When someone or something gets ignored or disregarded.